# character must be '0' or '1', found ' '

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My script

```
huffman_list =right[1:]+left[1:]
print(huffman_list)
huffman_dict = {a[0]:bitarray(str(a[1])) for a in huffman_list}
print(huffman_dict)
```

Result

```py
[['r', '000 '], ['t', '001 '], ['e', '01 '], ['y', '100 '], [' ', '1010 '],
 ['a', '1011 '], ['g', '1100 '], ['h', '1101 '], ['m', '1110 '],
 ['n', '1111 ']]
```

---

Getting the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-ef76e0d7e690> in <module>
      1 huffman_list =right[1:]+left[1:]
      2 print(huffman_list)
----> 3 huffman_dict = {a[0]:bitarray(str(a[1])) for a in huffman_list}
      4 print(huffman_dict)

<ipython-input-26-ef76e0d7e690> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 huffman_list =right[1:]+left[1:]
      2 print(huffman_list)
----> 3 huffman_dict = {a[0]:bitarray(str(a[1])) for a in huffman_list}
      4 print(huffman_dict)

ValueError: character must be '0' or '1', found ' '
```

Comment: Share your full code or find somewhere in your input has an empty value

Comment: All your strings have a space at the end that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
huffman_dict = {a[0]:bitarray(str(a[1]).trim()) for a in huffman_list}
```

The `trim` will remove the trailing spaces at the end of the strings.